# Stability Issues with Intrinsic Functions for RDMSR / WRMSR fixed by Switching to Assembly?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, x86-64, msr

I encountered problems while working on a project, specifically when dealing with intrinsic functions like `__rdtsc`, `__readmsr`, and `__writemsr` in Visual Studio. I noticed that using these functions was causing unexpected stability issues in my system, including my mouse becoming unresponsive. After some experimentation, I found a solution by manually coding the equivalent functionality in assembly.

Problem:
When using intrinsic functions to perform certain 64-bit operations, my system exhibited stability issues. This was particularly evident when trying to read from MSRs or using the timestamp counter.

Attempted Solutions:

- Checked for correct privilege levels and context for MSR operations.
- Ensured the latest updates for my development environment.
- Searched for known issues with these intrinsics or potential bugs in the compiler.

Working Solution:
I switched to using manual assembly within my code, specifically with the `rdmsr` instruction followed by `shl` and `or` operations to correctly handle the 64-bit result. This approach resolved the stability issues entirely.

Code Snippet:

```
rdmsr           ; Read MSR into EDX:EAX
shl rdx, 32     ; Shift the high 32 bits left
or rax, rdx     ; Combine the high and low parts
```

Has anyone else experienced similar issues with intrinsic functions in Visual Studio or other environments?
Are there known limitations or considerations with these intrinsics that I might have overlooked?
Could this solution imply a deeper underlying issue with my system's configuration or the compiler?

Environment:

- Compiler: visual studio 2019
- OS: Windows 10 version 20H2 build 19042.804
- Hardware: cpu AMD K10

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
unsigned __int64 AmdP0Freq() {
    unsigned __int64 msr = __readmsr(0xc0010064); // MSR address for P0 frequency
    int r = msr & 0x1f;
    __int64 hz = ((r + 0x10) * 100000000ll) / (1 << ((msr >> 6) & 0x07));
    return hz;
}
```

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: Sometimes undefined behavior stops manifesting (as fore example instability) after seemingly unrelated changes in code. It often will be back after some other seemingly unrelated changes in code.

Comment: I don't see a [mre], I'd expect a program I can run and reproduce your issue

Comment: @AlanBirtles: `rdmsr` is a privileged instruction (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdmsr), so you'd have to be willing to build a kernel driver, not a normal "program".  But yes, a MCVE is definitely needed here, unless MSVC is buggy, `__readmsr` should be equivalent to calling a stand-alone asm function that uses that ECX value.  Calling a non-inline function (which is necessarily the case for asm on MSVC for x64) can affect code-gen for the surrounding code, e.g. spilling variables to memory, so this could perhaps affect behaviour for an unrelated bug in the OP's code.

Comment: This question needs at least 3 more tags: [msvc][intrinsics], and probably [windows-kernel].  Unfortunately SO's tag limit is only 5.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Kh6aTeeM9 msvc implement __readmsr correct